# What are the most popular defences White should be prepared to fight against in the Ruy Lopez?

Tags: opening

Could you put the move orders as well as briefly explain the idea of the defenses?

Comment: Popular where and at what level? What club players play in one place may not be what GMs play, or club players play in another place.

Comment: @HerbWolfe What about popular in contemporary GM play?

Comment: Well if Carlsen-Anand WCC games have shown us anything, I think you should prepare against the Berlin defense.

Answer (score 5):

The mainlines and key ideas are highlighted in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_Lopez). The article covers:

### Morphy Defence: 3...a6

- Exchange Variation: 4.Bxc6
- Norwegian Defence: 4.Ba4 b5 5.Bb3 Na5
- Variations combining 3...a6 and ...Bc5
- Steinitz Defence Deferred: 4.Ba4 d6
- Schliemann Defence Deferred: 4.Ba4 f5
- Arkhangelsk Defence: 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.0-0 b5 6.Bb3 Bb7
- Mackenzie Variation 4. Ba4 Nf6 5.d4
- Russian Defence: 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.0-0 d6
- Open Defence: 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.0-0 Nxe4

### Closed Defence 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.0-0 Be7

- Delayed Exchange Variation Deferred: 6.Bxc6
- Centre Attack: 6.d4
- Worrall Attack: 6.Qe2
- Averbakh Variation: 6.Re1 d6
- Trajković Variation: 6.Re1 b5 7.Bb3 Bb7
- Marshall Attack: 7...0-0 8.c3 d5

### Main line: 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.0-0 Be7 6.Re1 b5 7.Bb3 d6 8.c3 0-0

- Pilnik Variation: 9.d3
- Yates Variation and Bogoljubow Variation: 9.d4
- Chigorin Variation: 9.h3 Na5
- Breyer Variation: 9.h3 Nb8
- Zaitsev Variation: 9.h3 Bb7
- Karpov Variation: 9.h3 Nd7
- Kholmov Variation: 9.h3 Be6
- Smyslov Variation: 9.h3 h6
- Smyslov Variation: 9.h3 Qd7

### Black defences other than 3...a6

- Cozio Defence: 3...Nge7
- Smyslov Defence: 3...g6
- Bird's Defence: 3...Nd4
- Steinitz Defence: 3...d6
- Schliemann Defence: 3...f5
- Classical Defence: 3...Bc5
- Berlin Defence: 3...Nf6

Comment: Great list.  If OP could narrow to specific line(s), we could answer the question better.